# Move photos from iCloud to iMac

Tags: icloud

I traded in my iPhone 4s for a 5s. I did not have time to transfer my photos at the store. My iPhone 5s says my iCloud is full and that the pictures are from my old phone. How do i get these photos out of the cloud and onto my iMac?

Answer (score 3):

Enable PhotoStream in iPhoto on your iMac.